# How to display archive page posts based on author_id

Tags: custom-post-type-archives, permalinks, authorization

I would like the posts to be displayed on archive page of custom post - `gallery` based on `author_id` i.e. the `author_id` is passed as permalink variable. The posts displayed on archive page would be only those posts published by author whose `author_id` is passed.

My custom post `gallery` archive page has the url `http://localhost/?post_type=gallery` where all the posts posted in the post_type - `gallery` are listed.

```
function my_custom_gallery() {
        $gallery_labels = array(
            'name' => _x('Gallery', 'post type general name'),
            'singular_name' => _x('Gallery', 'post type singular name'),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'gallery'),
            'add_new_item' => __("Add New Gallery"),
            'edit_item' => __("Edit Gallery"),
            'new_item' => __("New Gallery"),
            'view_item' => __("View Gallery"),
            'search_items' => __("Search Gallery"),
            'not_found' =>  __('No galleries found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No galleries found in Trash'), 
            'parent_item_colon' => ''               
        );
        $gallery_args = array(
            'labels' => $gallery_labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true, 
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => false,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'menu_position' => null,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'supports' => array('title'),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_position'      => 4,
            'menu_icon' =>  'dashicons-images-alt2'
        );

        register_post_type('gallery', $gallery_args);

    }
    add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_gallery' );
```

I have introduced a custom query variable using following function

```
function add_custom_query_var( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "custom_user_id";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );
```

I have rewritten my URL structure to contain the `custom_user_id`

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
$aNewRules = array('/gallery/user/([^/]+)?$' => 'index.php?post_type=gallery&custom_user_id=$matches[1]');
$aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
return $aRules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules'); 

function rewrite_flush(){
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $gallery_structure = '/gallery/%user_id%/%gallery%';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%gallery%", '([^/]+)', "gallery=");
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('gallery', $gallery_structure, false);
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init','rewrite_flush');


function tdd_permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename){ 
    $no_data = get_the_author_meta('ID');
    if($post->post_type != 'gallery' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft'))) return $permalink;
    $var1 = sanitize_title($no_data);
    $permalink = str_replace('%custom_user_id%', $var1, $permalink); 
    return $permalink; 
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'tdd_permalinks', 10, 3);
```

I retrive the custom query variable using `$query_author_id = get_query_var(custom_user_id)` and want the posts displayed whose author has the `author_id` - `$query_author_id` on the archive page.

Comment: What have your tried and where exactly do you need help? What it is `gallery`?

Comment: i have updated my post

Comment: i was actully trying to modify the core file...but am confused of what to do.

Comment: You cannot name your custom post type `gallery`, it is a reserved name in core, rename it to something like galleries

Comment: Well the thing is that I have done it and no error has occurred to me yet.... I would like to know what should I do to achieve my goal ?

Comment: I visited this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms) ...and did not find gallery in reserved terms there

Comment: I don't think registering a post type with `gallery` name is a problem. Anyway, the update of your question doesn't describe where do you need help and what you have tried, how you pass the `author_id`, what the archive page is (i.e. page template, archive template, ...), etc. Please, describe your problem accurately and where do you need help. As it is, it can there be a lot of good answers.

Comment: @cybmeta ...I have updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to use `pre_get_posts` action to hook to add `author_id` to the query based on your custom `custom_user_id` query var:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_by_custom_user_id' );
function filter_by_custom_user_id( $query ) {

    // Apply only on frontend, for gallery post type archive, for main query and if custom_user_id query var is set.
    if( ! is_admin()
        && $query->is_main_query()
        && is_post_type_archive( 'gallery' )
        && isset( $query->query_vars['custom_user_id'] ) {

            $query->set( 'author_id', (int) $query->query_vars['custom_user_id'] );
    }

}
```

**IMPORTANT**: I see that you are flushing rewrite rules on every page load using `init` action hook. Flusing rewrite rules should be done only on plugin activation and deactivation. Other than that hooks, flushing rewrite rules should be done only specifically when you know that rewrite rules have changed and they need to be rebuilt. Note that flushing rewrite rules perform dabase operations that are not needed to do only one time, not on every page load.